# drupal 6 and views node form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-modules, cck

is there a way to create a view of a node & cck and dispaly it as editable field like node_form_edit ? so it will have edit/add/view states ?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you should take a look at the [Editable Fields module](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields).  This allows fields to be edited while in the "view" state of a node.